# NullPointerException from OnClickListeners of Buttons inside expandableListView

Tags: java, android

Here is the problem: I have an activity which contains an **expandableListView**, inside of each group I want to show obviously the items plus a **button** which has to start another activity which allows to create another item and add it to the list.

I already managed to create the button, (to do this an empty child is put inside of each group in the last position and in the getChildView when we get the to the last child (the empty child) the view of the button is created).
Here is the code:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(isLastChild){
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_btn, null);
        Intent i = new Intent(_context,Menu.class);
        i.putExtra("WorkoutPosition", groupPosition);
        return convertView;
    }

    ...
}
```

And this is the XML code of the button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+ New Exercise"
        android:id="@+id/newExBtn"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

That works fine but when I try too set the OnClickListener a NullPointerException is thrown.

Here is the code:

```
Button newExBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newExBtn);
    newExBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
        ...
```

Here is the exception I get:

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
     Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference`

It seems that I'm trying to set Listeners on buttons that doesn't exist but I can't understand why and who to fix this. 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please provide the XML for the `list_btn` layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're calling the `findViewById()` in the `Activity`, maybe even before attaching the new inflated layout to it. As `findViewById()` iterates recursively from the root of the `Activity` (the layout you use with `setContentView()`), it will not find this button until you attach it to the `Activity` (that's why you get a `null`).

You're code should be instead something like:

```
Button newExBtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.newExBtn);
newExBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    ...
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what do you suggest to do :(
You mean to put the declaration of the onClick method inside the ExpandableListAdapter class? But this way I cannot make another activity to start with the startActivity method right? I'm confused.
There's not a way to attach the the layout on the activity and then set the listener?

Comment: The `onClick` method should be in the adapter. You can pass the `Activity` to the `ExpandableListAdapter`.